# SocketTimeoutException from one AppEngine Server to another

Tags: google-app-engine

We are a Premier Account User in GoogleAppEngine. We have two front-end servers running on Google AppEngine developed using Java.

Front-end server A communicates with another front-end server B using URLFetch(java.net) request.

We have set the maximum connectionTimeOut and readTimeOuts (60000ms) also for URLFetch in server A.

All the requests from server A to B works successfully 70% of the time.

But we are finding weird scenarios like 30% of the time where server A would have given URLFetch request to Server B and throwing java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Timeout while fetching URL.

Note: The request from Server A to B remains dead air for 60 seconds and there aren't any request being received at Server B for the same. There are no instance restarts on both the servers.

But when the client retries the request again, it runs successfully.

We have 2 idle instances and instance classes configured to F4 on both the servers.

Can we please know why the request from Server A timeouts out without a request being received at the other server end (ie) Server B?

Thanks.

Regards,
Anantha Krishnan

Comment: Are the timed out requests occurring when a frontend B instance starts ?  Are they all the same appid ?  Any particular reason why your B instance isn't a backend ?

Comment: No instance restarts on both Server A and Server B. There is no particular reason as to tell why we aren't using backend for Server B.

Comment: Unless they are on different appid's why would you have a frontend talk to another frontend.  It would seem to make sense for frontend -> backend.

Comment: And if your frontends are different appid's then you may be in breach of TOS.

Comment: Thanks for your quick responses. Can you please incorporate more reasons as to how it will solve this SocketTimeOutException if we go in for backend in Server B?

Comment: You said in your original question that when you retry it works, so don't wait to long. Say 5secs.  Then trap the Deadline exception and retry the request.  As to the backend, I would only suggest that it might improve the situation if they are all the same appid.

Comment: Definitely Server A is not exceeding the per minute quota for URLFetch API Calls(32,000 calls per min.As you have suggested, we deployed the Server B as backend module and Server A as frontend module in the same App ID and used URLFetch in module A(Server A) to communicate with module B (Server B) of the same app.Still the same error.The only thing we need to test now with modules is cut down the URLFetch in module A(Server A) and communicate directly with module B(Server B).Technically we need to integrate the codebase of Server B inside module A(Server A).This we can try out from our end.

Comment: But my question is,imagine there are two different organisation using AppEngine and one of the sever in the organisation running in AppEngine needs to communicate with the server in the other organisation running same in AppEngine, they have to communicate with URLFetch calls only.We cannot force the organisations to create one common App and use modules to avoid SocketTimeOutExceptions.Can you please give the appropriate reasons/solutions for the same?Please let me know if you need any other information regarding this.

Comment: Hi,

FYI: As you have suggested, we deployed the Server B as backend module and Server A as frontend module in the same App ID and used URLFetch in module A(Server A) to communicate with module B (Server B) of the same app. Still the same problem for one user who is using the application and that's me. So there is no question of exceeding the per minute quota limits or any other for that matter.

Comment: As you have quoted: Longer-term, the even better option would be to refactor your application code so shared services are available as libraries and not as individual endpoints.Libraries will increase the size of the application.Deploying the app with libraries is old fashion.Its not good to follow if you consider the growth of the application. REST based service is the current trend.All this together, does that mean SOA (Service Oriented Architecture) or REST API Services will fluctuate in Google AppEngine (ie) from AppEngine Server to another AppEngine Server very often?